Swifui button image is stretching across the entire streen
I am not sure how to get the image to stay in a reasonable size, being new to SwiftUI I have no doubt that this is completely my fault.

The code is as follows:
import SwiftUI

struct AnimalsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                    HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: ManagementView()) {
                                ZStack {
                                    Image("Button-Normal")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                                    Text("Breeding")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                }
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: AnimalsView()) {
                                ZStack {
                                    Image("Button-Normal")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .padding()
                                
                                    
                                    
                                    Text("Animals")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    HStack {
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        
                    }
                }
                
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Logout") {
                        Task {
                            let Signout = SignOutLocally()
                            await Signout.signOutLocally()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background {
                Image("Rancher1")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    AnimalsView()
}

The first button has a frame defined with height and width but I know that Apple strongly suggests staying away from that.
I know some developers prefer to use the NavigationLink as the button itself, and I have tried that as well but it never acts correctly.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

There is nothing wrong with using .frame(width: height:), Apple examples often use it
to size  pictures/photos/images Views etc..., eg Sample Apps tutorial  and https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/imagegallery#Creating-a-Grid-Item  and many more. Frame the Image or its enclosing container. There is also .frame with maxWidth and maxHeight.

I'm ok with that however the buttons on ipad devices should be a different size, is there a way to define that in the same code?

What do you mean by "the buttons on ipad devices should be a different size"? Please be very clear and specific about what you want.

You can use the max/min width/height, Aspect ratio, etc. to constrain the button some more.

You need a better grasp on SwiftUI basics, like layout, combining views and defining structs. ZStacks are fun but they're not the answer to everything.
Everything inside the NavigationLink in your case should be a struct that accepts a text parameter, or a styled Button.
You don't need a trillion ZStacks for this layout. See how I did it below and compare. Notice the use of only two stacks to achieve the intended layout. I left the background as yellow, you can set your own image as an exercise.
import SwiftUI

struct FarmView: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    enum Destination: Hashable {
        case red
        case orange
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            VStack{
                Text("Select an interest:")
                HStack {
                    Button("Breeding"){
                        path.append(Destination.orange)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(OrangeButtonStyle())
                    
                    Button("Animals"){
                        path.append(Destination.red)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(OrangeButtonStyle())
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Logout") {
                    //action here...
                }
                .tint(.black)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background{
                Color.yellow //or the image of your choice
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Welcome")
            // .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inlineLarge)
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                    case .orange:
                        BreedingView()
                    case .red:
                        AnimalsView()
                }
            }
        }
        .tint(.white)
    }
}

struct OrangeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background {
                LinearGradient(colors: [.white.opacity(0.9), .yellow, .orange, .orange], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(.black.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 10)
            }
            .scaleEffect(1.2)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct AnimalsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationTitle("Red View")
        }

    }
}

struct BreedingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.orange
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .navigationTitle("Orange View")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FarmView()
}

I didn't use a NavigationLink in order to use a Button and show how you can control navigation without a navigation link, which gives you the flexibility to use any view, as needed, or none at all (and navigate by changing the path in a function, as the part of whatever logic).
I suggest you go through the tutorials again and make sure you can execute a basic layout like this without trouble.


Andrei, thank you for the clear and polite explanation.  Much appreciated.  I will go through the tutorials.
